# IEnumerable data not passing back from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC4 Project view am passing `IEnumerable<Settings>` model to view. When i submit the form back to my controller, the controller method is having parameter as `IEnumerable<Settings> data`. The problem is that `data` is always null.

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Settings>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Layout", FormMethod.Post)))
{
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsActive, new { @value = item.Id })
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<Settings> data)
{
    --actual code goes here
}
```

**Model**

```
[Serializable]
public class Settings
{   
    public virtual byte Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual DataTable DataResult { get; set; }

    public virtual int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual int ClientId { get; set; }

    public virtual Int16 NoofItems { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**
**Rendered HTML**

```
<td>
    <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsActive field is required." id="item_IsActive" name="item.IsActive" type="checkbox" value="13" class="valid"><input name="item.IsActive" type="hidden" value="false">
                                # of pieces

                                </td>
```

**Update1:**
Rendered HTML after following answer by Andrei

```
<td>
     <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsActive field is required." name="[0].IsActive" type="checkbox" value="13"><input name="[0].IsActive" type="hidden" value="false">
                                    # of pieces</td>
```

Comment: Is your controller method hit?

Comment: @BhushanFirake, yes it hits, and from there only i analyzed with immediate window and the data is null

Comment: post code of Index action method, how are you returning result from controller?

Comment: @SanjeevRai, I will be passing `Collection<Settings>` as view model...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsActive, new { @value = item.Id })
```

is not going to generate right name for the input. Your form sends the same token `item.IsActive=true` (or false) for all items. While this approach works for primitives, it does not work for complex types.

However here is what you can do using `for` instead of `foreach`:

```
@model IList<Settings>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @for(int i=0; i<Model.Count; i++)
    {
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsActive, new { @value = Model[i].Id })
       @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Notice that this requires at least `IList<>` as a view type - otherwise you cannot iterate through the collection using `for`.

Comment: +1, Hi this works partially, now the data is not null, but the property `IsActive` is always `false` and `Is` is always. I meant to say to its all having the default property values instead of the posted one...

Comment: @SSS, how does you model class `Settings` look like? And furthermore, what HTML is being generated now for checkbox?

Comment: @SSS, for some reason you have two inputs there, one is checkbox and the other on is hidden. They have the same name, and both are posted (for each item), and apparently the latter, hidden one, is picked up by MVC. Since all hiddens have theier value set to `false`, this is what you are getting. I am not sure where this hidden input comes from, but you need to remove it or give it a different name for checkboxes to work correctly.

Comment: thanks for you time and i accept your answer and i just fixed by removing the value field from checkbox and i had it in another hidden field and now it is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Might need to wrap your inputs in a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsActive, new { @value = item.Id })
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
   }
   <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: i already added that, just added the part of the code. see my updates

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the renderred html?

Here is the problem I think:
The names of the inputs (checkboxes) are going to be `IsActive` in html. When you hit submit, the form will submit the data with key `IsActive`. In your controller you are currently expecting a parameter called `data` so there is a mismatch.

You can troubleshoot this by adding a breakpoint in the controller and checking whether Request["IsActive"] has a value.

UPDATE:
You can take a look [here](http://neimke.blogspot.nl/2011/01/pass-array-of-integers-to-controller.html) for a walkthrough:

I think you can try first to change the `name` of the input to `data`. You can try to do that with:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsActive, new { @value = item.Id, name="data" })
```

After you change it, the form should submit a comma separated list of values to the controller. Can you open firebug as well and post here what gets posted to the controller?

Comment: Might also work to have `bool[] IsActive, string[] Name` as parameters

Comment: +1, valuable suggestion and is checked `Request["IsActive"] at immediate window and the value is null

Comment: @sTodorov I updated my question with rendered HTML can u pls check ?